# Where are the Shape Key Editor / Fake User Setting?

Tags: shape-keys

I've just picked up Blender again after almost 2 years and was stocked to see that 2.8 looks and feels amazing.
What isn't so amazing is that the layout has changed and almost all tutorials use the old layout.

I want to export a shape key animation to .fbx in order to use it in Spark AR. A simple location animation has worked but for shape keys, in all tutorials I've encountered, you need to open the shape key editor and check the F for fake user.

I can't find this setting anywhere. Where is it?

Comment: Now its a shield icon at the same place where the F was.

Comment: thanks for the answer
but the f was in the shape key editor wasn't it? and i can't find that either

Answer (score 0):

I found the shape key editor and as @FFeller pointed out the F was replaced by a shield icon.
For some reason the shape key editor doesn't show up in the Layout workspace but when I changed to Animation it was there.